# Filter first element in a list that matches a criteria for each row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, filtering

Question/Issue: I'd like to create another column that contains the first column (of many)/or value in a list that matches a criteria (which is to be different than "nan").

I am working on a dataframe that has mutliple columns that serve as flags, each column is a different kind of a flag. This is what it looks like:

```
         id_number  createdat  ... flag_3.3.3.2.1 flag_3.3.3.2.2 flag_3.3.3.3.1
1             718v 2019-08-14  ...            nan      3.3.3.2.2      3.3.3.3.1
2             566m 2019-07-10  ...            nan            nan            nan
3             636p 2019-06-12  ...      3.3.3.2.1            nan      3.3.3.3.1
4             630r 2019-06-30  ...            nan            nan            nan
26815         066p 2019-08-24  ...      3.3.3.2.1      3.3.3.2.2      3.3.3.3.1
26816         769b 2019-08-10  ...            nan            nan            nan
```

I've managed to create a column that generates a list of all the values of columns that contain "flag_":

```
payday_cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('flag_')]
df['flagging'] = df[payday_cols].values.tolist()
print(df)
         id_number  ... flag_3.3.3.3.1                                           flagging
1             718v  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
2             566m  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
3             636p  ...            nan  [nan, nan, 2.2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
4             630r  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, 3.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.3.2...                                          ...
26815         066p  ...      3.3.3.3.1  [nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.2, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
26816         769b  ...            nan  [1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.3.2.1...
```

What I'm missing is a way to create a final column that contains the first value of the list that is different to `nan`, or nan if there's no value that's different to `nan`. The output would be this:

```
         id_number  ... flag_3.3.3.3.1                                           flagging      flag
1             718v  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...       nan
2             566m  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...       nan
3             636p  ...            nan  [nan, nan, 2.2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...       2.2
4             630r  ...            nan  [nan, nan, nan, 3.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.3.2...       3.1
26815         066p  ...      3.3.3.3.1  [nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.2, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...       3.2
26816         769b  ...            nan  [1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.3.2.1...   3.3.2.1
```

Thanks a lot and if you need me to generate values similar to these ones so you can recreate this case I'll edit this post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "flagging": [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 2.2, np.nan, 0.2], [np.nan, 1.1, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.1]]
})

def get_element(xs):
    xs = [x for x in xs if not pd.isna(x)]
    if xs:
        return xs[0]
    return np.nan

df["flagging"].apply(get_element)
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    2.2
2    1.1
3    3.1
```

Comment: It is true, I could have a used list comprehension within a function and then apply it to generate the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**:

Try `bfill` and `.iloc`

```
df[payday_cols].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]

Out[92]:
1        3.3.3.2.2
2              NaN
3        3.3.3.2.1
4              NaN
26815    3.3.3.2.1
26816          NaN
Name: flag_3.3.3.2.1, dtype: object
```

---

**Method 2**:

Another solution is using numpy `argmax` on `notna` and pass the result to `lookup`

```
m = df[payday_cols].notna().values.argmax(1)
df[payday_cols].lookup(df.index, np.array(payday_cols)[m])

Out[145]: array(['3.3.3.2.2', nan, '3.3.3.2.1', nan, '3.3.3.2.1', nan], dtype=object)
```

---

Note: output is based on this sample

```
In [83]: df

Out[83]:
      id_number   createdat flag_3.3.3.2.1 flag_3.3.3.2.2 flag_3.3.3.3.1  
1          718v  2019-08-14            NaN      3.3.3.2.2      3.3.3.3.1
2          566m  2019-07-10            NaN            NaN            NaN
3          636p  2019-06-12      3.3.3.2.1            NaN      3.3.3.3.1
4          630r  2019-06-30            NaN            NaN            NaN
26815      066p  2019-08-24      3.3.3.2.1      3.3.3.2.2      3.3.3.3.1
26816      769b  2019-08-10            NaN            NaN            NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to a minor fix on my behalf and it's fully functional!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to:

- Convert the column containing the lists to a *DataFrame* (applying
  *pd.Series* to each element).
- Apply to each row a function based on *first_valid_index*.

So let's assume that *df* is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "flagging": [
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 2.2, np.nan, 0.2],
    [np.nan, 1.1, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.1]]})
```

Define the following function:

```
def func(x):
    ind = x.first_valid_index()
    return None if ind is None else x[ind]
```

Then apply it:

```
df.flagging.apply(pd.Series).apply(func, axis=1)
```